# Windows 7 taskbar adds additional icons for already pinned icons

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

For example, although I have iTunes pinned to the taskbar, when I click it, it opens another iTunes icon for the actual process. Is there a fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some taskbar pinned icons are duplicated when an instance of the application is running](http://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpin then repin the icon.

Comment: pretty much. figured out that if I unpin the initial program icon while the program is running and then I pin the running program to the taskbar, this fixes the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just wonder if you have the Taskbar properties set to Never Combine.
Right-click Start Orb, Properties, Taskbar, Taskbar buttons.  Try the options including 'Never Combine'.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this still occurs with "always combine" enabled.  If you pin the new button, then unpin the old button, it should solve the issue.