# Pinning programs to bar in Windows sometimes duplicates icons

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some taskbar pinned icons are duplicated when an instance of the application is running](https://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is)

I love the feature in Windows 7 of pinning programs to the Task Bar, though I'm really confused about some of the behavior:

**Situation 1:**

> I pinned Firefox to the task bar.  Now, when I launch Firefox, one Firefox icon shows in the back bar, and clicking that icon opens the running Firefox window.

**Situation 2:**

> I pinned Eclipse to the task bar.  Now, when I click the Eclipse icon, a duplicate icon appears next to the existing Eclipse icon.  This results in two Eclipse icons in the task bar; clicking the original opens a new Eclipse instance, and clicking the duplicate one re-opens the running instance.

I prefer situation 1, where only one icon stays on my task bar, and clicking that icon opens the running program.  What is causing this happen?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You might have installed Eclipse as a "portable" installation.

A potential fix:

1. Click the application in taskbar
2. Wait for duplicate icon to activate
3. Right click un-activated icon and "unpin from taskbar"
4. Right click activated icon and "pin to taskbar"
5. Close app
6. Click application in taskbar

This should give you the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Works for me with eclipse!