# How do I pin minecraft directly to my taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some taskbar pinned icons are duplicated when an instance of the application is running](https://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is)

So for those of you who don't know you can have your taskbar set up like this:

[image]

However, when I click the minecraft icon, my taskbar looks like this:

[image]

Right clicking on minecraft game:

[image]

Why does this happen? How can I directly link to the game?