# Duplicate icons on taskbar in IntelliJ – Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, intellij-idea

I have an issue with IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio when I pin the icons to my taskbar. If I click on the icon, the actual window opens in a smaller duplicate icon on the taskbar rather than opening the window in the pinned icon.

I have tried uninstalling with Revo Uninstaller Pro and reinstalling, but to no avail. Copying the `.exe` file directly to the `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` folder doesn't work – the icon does not appear.

This is not a duplicate of this question: [Some taskbar pinned icons are duplicated when an instance of the application is running](https://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is)

I have tried all the suggested solutions from the earlier question, to check, but there is still a duplicate icon, so maybe it is a problem with Windows 10 specifically. I do not have any problems with any other programs.

Comment: I concur, this is occurring on Windows 10 with Java-based applications like IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse.  Compatibility mode (to Windows 8 or Windows 7) didn't solve it, either.

Comment: I have edited the post to add some more details on possible solutions I have tried. Thank you

Comment: @Scott - I have updated the question to clarify this is not a duplicate: it is specific to windows 10 and intelliJ, as I have tried all the solutions mentioned, and neither of them work. The programs worked fine on windows 8.1 until I upgraded. Thank you.

Comment: I think there is only one proper solution for this kind of bugs and that's reporting it to the software developers. I've created issue ticket for this so if you want to have it fix, go there and vote for that (you have to be logged in). [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145590](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145590)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DISCLAIMER]

This is not actually a fix, more of a hack to make this work since it annoyed the hell out of me.

---

First of all, you need to find out what the AppID of the app (here IntelliJ) is. To do this, you can use [Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) (you can uninstall it afterwards).
Open the program and go to Taskbar Inspector. The string next to the arrow is the AppID.

*The current EAP version has the AppID: "IntelliJ IDEA (Minerva).-1274214200"
but be sure to check, if it doesn't work (release versions of IntelliJ have different IDs)*

The next thing you need is mkshortcut.exe which will create a custom shortcut for you. Check out this [walk-through](http://portableapps.com/node/31515) and follow all the steps replacing the target with the file path of idea.exe or idea64.exe and the appid with the one above.

If you now start IntelliJ from anywhere, it should group properly with the pinned icon.

Btw. This is a simplified version of this walk-through: neowin.net/forum/topic/985014-guide-pin-programs-with-custom-launchers-to-taskbar/

Comment: Walkthrough and neowin links are now broken for me.

Comment: Me too.  Could you post a description of how to solve the problem?  In the meantime, it's possible to view Google's [cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IPJkJ5RPedwJ:portableapps.com/node/31515+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk).

Comment: @Conan, thanks for the chuckle. Maybe you realized, but you said 'Me too' to your past self. :) The links seem to be working fine now, so it might have been a temporary issue.

Comment: Oh, ha! This must have really been annoying me lately! I gave this a try but with no joy. Maybe JetBrains will fix the issue again - I think it's a regression.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be working for me.

Open your idea.properties file (located in /bin) and add this line at the bottom `windows.jumplist=false`

Comment: Note that this will remove the jump list capability (right-click list of recent projects).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known Windows 10 issue and should be fixed when build 10565 is pushed to everyone. You can join the [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/) to get "Insider builds" in advance.

> **Here are some things we have fixed:**
>
> ...
>
> Certain apps won’t appear
>   twice anymore when pinned to the taskbar.

([source](http://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10565/))

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sync the appbar icon Adding Android Studio to it AFTER it has been launched, simply pinning it from the application bar.

Trying to add the icon in other ways in Win10 produce the duplicate icon issue, so I'm using this method to add the shortcut.