# Prevent Windows 11 Sandbox from creating an instance icon in taskbar

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, sandbox

I'm running Windows 11 Pro 21H2. I activated Windows Sandbox and pinned it (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsSandbox.exe) to the taskbar. Now, whenever I run Windows Sandbox, another icon of it appears in the taskbar. So, I have two icons, one for the program, another for the instance.

How do I prevent Sandbox from creating the instance icon? I know it can be done because I saw it on another computer (not mine).

I found the following related links. Both didn't work for me.
[Duplicate icons on taskbar in IntelliJ – Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954300/duplicate-icons-on-taskbar-in-intellij-windows-10)
[Some taskbar pinned icons are duplicated when an instance of the application is running](https://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is)

Answer (score 2):

Sandbox is built into Windows 11 Pro (and 10 Pro).

Best you do not try to use your own shortcuts and icons.

Sandbox will do it for you.

Just let Windows manage it and it will work much better.